# Would a question regarding the value of jQuery vs. Javascript be appropriate for Pro Webmasters?

Tags: discussion, suitable-question

Recently on Stack Overflow a question popped up regarding whether jQuery still had any real value over just using JavaScript and was shot down for being: not a real question, likely to elicit extended discussion and debate, etc...

The OP seemed to think that it was a valid question that needed serious consideration and a solid canonical answer and I'm inclined to agree that the question deserves a good answer, but I'm also inclined to believe that it wasn't a good fit for SO.

Would such a question be welcome on Pro Webmasters?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, for the same reasons provided at SO - any "versus" questions without the context of solving a specific problem are bound to fall prey to ideological argument.

If a question is grounded in practice - e.g. "Which is more efficient for XYZ purpose?" - it may have a shot, but generally "versus" questions are avoided, they're simply not constructive to the *practice* of programming or webmastering.

Comment: Thanks, I thought that would be the case.

Comment: That being said, if you're looking for an extended discussion, [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/) is here expressly for such purposes :)

Comment: Plus it's about programming, so even if it wasn't a discussion question, it's still off topic.

Comment: i can think of questions where this *may* be legitimate ... what about performance versus questions? "I have feature A on my site, should I replace it with feature B/replace the backend to backend C ", etc.?

Comment: @DKOATED But wouldn't that end up being not constructive/too localized, by virtue of config parameters? (Can't assume any two installations are the same)

Comment: @danlefree true. i didn't think of that ...